# If error messages echo line content

Tags: function, vim, echo

I try to capture lines with calculations in my text document
and execute them.

I use this in my function:

```
for i in range(startline,endline) 
let calculation = getline(i)  
...  
let out = eval(calculation)  
...  
endfor
```

sometimes something goes wrong and I receive this message:

```
Error detected while processing function....  
Line ...  
E488: Trailing Characters
```

Line .. is the line-nr in my function.
I would like to know also which calculation it concerns (which line in my text doc):

If Error detected = echo calculation

How can I check if there is an error message and echo the variable "calculation"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to handle script errors inside a function:

The first is suppressing the error via `:silent!`. Two downsides: You have to manually check for success, and any normal output from the evaluated script is suppressed, too (unless you do contortions with `:unsilent`).

```
let v:errmsg = ''
silent! let out = eval(calculation)
if v:errmsg != ''
    " error
endif
```

I would recommend the second way via try...catch, which avoids the issues with the output and having to explicitly check for an error:

```
try
    let out = eval(calculation)
catch /^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:E/
    " v:exception contains what is normally in v:errmsg, but with extra
    " exception source info prepended, which we cut away.
    let v:errmsg = printf("Line: %d\nCalculation: %s\nError: %s", i, calculation, substitute(v:exception, '^Vim\%((\a\+)\)\=:', '', ''))
    echohl ErrorMsg
    echomsg v:errmsg
    echohl None
endtry
```

Comment: thank you very much Ingo. I adapted your 2nd solution. Just one little thing. I added `: continue` under `echohl None` in order to go to the next loop. What I want is that the error messages are shown at the end of the function (after everything is done). Is that possible?

Comment: @remio: Sure. Initialize a List via `let errors = []` before the loop. Then, instead of assigning to `v:errmsg`, do `call add(errors, printf(...))`. Finally, after the loop, print the list either via `echo join(errors, "\n")` or explicitly iterating via `for error in errors`.